# macOS differences running application in Finder and Terminal?

Tags: c++, macos, terminal

I'm developing a C++ application using Qt Creator.  When I look in the Finder, I see the output in:

```
    build-XMLMPAM-Desktop_Qt_5_11_2_clang_64bit-Debug
```

This folder contains the object files "moc" cpp files.  In the finder I see the application:

```
    XMLMPAM.app
```

Whilst I can launch this from Finder, when I open a terminal, this is actually a folder.  Containing files and sub folders.

In order to launch the application from the terminal I have to enter:

```
    ~/build-XMLMPAM-Desktop_Qt_5_11_2_clang_64bit-Debug/XMLMPAM.app/Contents/MacOS/XMLMPAM
```

From the application I am reporting the CWD:

When launched from the terminal or from Qt Creator debugger:

```
    CWD:  /Users/Simon/build-XMLMPAM-Desktop_Qt_5_11_2_clang_64bit-Debug/XMLMPAM.app/Contents/MacOS
```

When launched from Finder:

```
    CWD:  /
```

I'm confused by this, what is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A macOS app like `XMLMPAM.app` is indeed a folder. In Apple terms it is called a *bundle*. It is a directory with a certain structure that OS and other utilities can recognize. The actual executable program file is located inside Contents/MacOS subfolder of the bundle. That is where Finder is locating it. Finder pretends that it is a cohesive "file", but you can also go inside the bundle by right-click and "Show Package Contents".

If you want to simulate the Finder behaviour from the terminal, run `open XMLMPAM.app` or `open -a XMLMPAM`.

If you want to get the path of the bundle, or any file inside it you can use methods of the [NSBundle class](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle). For example: `NSBundle.mainBundle.executableURL.path` should give you the full path to your app's executable file.